# How do we start robot-remote-server-library with arguments?

Tags: arguments, robotframework, remote-server

how do we start robot-remote-server with arguments?
myServerlibrary is supposed to start from a certain work directory and load environment from that specific directory.

```
class myServerLibrary(object):
def __init__(self, workdir=DEFAULTS.WORKDIR, loadscript=DEFAULTS.STARTUP):
    self.workdir = workdir
    self.loadscript = loadscript
```

Need to start the remote-server as a commandline or in /etc/rc.local

```
python myServerLibrary.py 127.0.0.1 8720 /home/abc
```